# Adding two normal distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are i.i.d. normal random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. And Suppose that $Z \sim N(1, 2^2)$ and is independent of all $X_i$. Define $Z_i = Z + X_i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$. What is the distribution of the random vector $Z$?

I guess it is also normal but I don't know how exactly why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full answer to your question of why the answer is still normal requires appeal to a highly desirable property of the normal distribution: that it is a [stable distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution). The theory of stable distributions requires characteristic equations and somewhat advanced, measure theoretic/real analytic arguments. Suffice it to say, most statisticians simply accept this fact, and henceforth just remember that linear combinations of normal variables are indeed normal.

In your case, your formulation is essentialy creating a multivariate normal vector with a gaussian "effect" added to it. Therefore, the resulting multivariate vector will again be a multivariate normal, but with a mean vector of $\mathbf{1}$ (since each X has mean 0 and Z has mean 1). However, the presence of the *same* Z in each term means that the resulting multivariate distribution is no longer a set of iid variables, since the common Z induces a correlation. As Dilip has pointed out, these covariances will be:

$cov(X_i+Z,X_j+Z)=cov(X_i,X_j)+cov(X_i,Z)+cov(Z,X_j)+cov(Z,Z)=\sigma^2_Z$ As all the other terms become zero due to independence.

Therefore, the correlation between any two elements of the resulting multivariate normal vector, ($X_i+Z,X_j+Z)$, will be $\rho = \frac{cov(X_i+Z,X_j+Z)}{\sqrt{\sigma_i^2+\sigma_Z^2}+ \sqrt{\sigma_j^2+\sigma_Z^2}}=\frac{4}{2\sqrt{5}}\approx .0.89$ Resulting in quite a strong linear relationship between the variables.

Comment: This is all correct, but please bear in mind that $X,Y$ have to have a _joint_ normal distribution for $X+Y$ to be normal.  If $X,Y$ have marginal normal distributions then they need not be jointly normal, even if they are uncorrelated!

Comment: @JPi Very True (+1). Normal marginals $\neq$ joint normal. However, the assertion that the X's are iid normal is sufficient to conclude joint normality. If they were simply normal but correlated or unknown dependence (even if covariance is zero), then we cannot assume stability, as you have said.

Comment: Independence indeed implies joint normality, but they can be uncorrelated and normal without being jointly normal!

Comment: @JPi I think I mentioned that in the second part of my comment (in parentheses)...but it is one of those points that cant be said clearly and strongly enough, many people, including myself if I'm not careful, will quickly jump from normal + uncorrelated to joint-normal, so bringing this out as a separate statement is a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

$(Z_1, Z_2, Z_3)$ is obtained by a *linear transformation* applied to the vector $(X_1, X_2, X_3, Z)$ which is a *normal* vector; the four random variables are *jointly normal*.  Linear transformations on jointly normal random variables give jointly normal random variables (that is, $(Z_1, Z_2, Z_3)$ is also a
normal vector) and you can *write down* the joint density if you
can figure out the means of the $Z_i$ (hint: use the *linearity of expectation*) and
the variances and
*covariances* of the random variables. You can either use a matrix formulation
or 
$$\operatorname{cov}(A+B, C+D) = \operatorname{cov}(A,C) + \operatorname{cov}(A,D) + \operatorname{cov}(B,C) + \operatorname{cov}(B,D)$$ to get the covariances.